# How to use XPath to get all text from within <p> element including any href links and their link text

Tags: python, xpath

I've read all the other related topics but I was unable to combine them into a working solution. I just can't read the entire contents of a paragraph. If it contains <span> I don't get the containing text at all and if it contains <a href> link I only get the link text without the actual URL. Can anyone help?

Example:

```
tree = etree.HTML('<div id="classy"><span>this is </span><p>Some text, then this link: <a href="http://www.violentpower.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> Insane website</a> and some more text here.</p></div>')
_result = tree.xpath('//div[@id="classy"]//descendant::p')

for article in _result:
    _output = etree.tostring(article, pretty_print=True)

print _output
```

I'm looking to get this result:

this is Some text, then this link: http://www.violentpower.com/  Insane website and some more text here.

...but I get this instead:
<p>Some text, then this link:  Insane website and some more text here.</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select

```
result = tree.xpath("//div[@id = 'classy']//text() | //div[@id = 'classy']//@href")
```

you get a list

```
['this is ', 'Some text, then this link: ', 'http://www.violentpower.com/', ' Insane website', ' and some more text here.']
```

you can then join all strings into a single one with

```
''.join(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, good sir! I actually tried the pipe but I must have messed up something else because it didn't work. Now it even works without re-defining the same container. This works too: //text()|//@href